# Does Micronaut have Grails equivalent of assetResourceLocator?

Tags: grails, groovy, micronaut

Does Micronaut have something like the assetResourceLocator in Grails? I want to load a CSV from the project directory at startup. And where should I put my CSV file into?

Comment: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/cli/io/support/ResourceLocator.html

Comment: @Rcordoval I think that is only relevant at build time.